# How to do a OR statement for stripos?

Tags: php, security, validation

How do i add another condition to the same snippet below? I need to add a "OR" condition where $variable = $variable?

```
 if ( stripos($userallowed, $sid) !== false ) {
 echo("allowed");
 } else {
 echo("not allowed");
 die();
 }
```

Comment: `if ( stripos($userallowed, $sid) !== false OR $variable == $variable )`...?

Comment: Thanks that worked.  If you post it as an answer i can select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( stripos($userallowed, $sid) !== false OR $variable == $variable )
```

Comment: You should use `||` and `&&` instead.

Comment: I know that that's the more typical style, but there's little difference between the two, and the OP's bigger problem seems to be to grasp the concept at all. So I'm not going overboard with optimizations and style here...